# jquery Arrays, how to use each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I current have the following which works well:

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    members.each(set_status_online);
})


function set_status_online(member) {
    var user_temp;
    user_temp = findWallUser(member.info.uid);
    if (user_temp) {
        user_temp.status('online');
    }
    else {
        console.log('user not found');
    }
}
```

I am trying to update the first part to give me more control of the members.each. I want something like this:

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    members.each {
       set_status('online');
    }
})
```

Is there a way I can do that with the array & .each? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With arrays, use `$.each` like this:

```
$.each(members,set_status_online);
```

Change your function to have the `index` as the first variable:

```
function set_status_online(index,member) {
etc...
}
```

Or if you don't want to modify your function, you can do this with the `$.each`:

```
$.each(members,function(i,e){
  set_status_online(e)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    members.each(function(member) {
       set_status('online', member);
    });
})

function set_status(setStatusToWhat, member) { //setStatusToWhat would be 'online'
    ;
}
```